# Spring Roo and EhCache

Tags: ehcache, spring-roo

roo-1.3.1.RC1.
I created simple 3-4 tables with proper PK and FK relations. 
I loaded data into it.
I use spring-roo - reverse engg techniques to generate the JSF based UI.
I have a List of Employees which are showing in the default JSF generated page with proper pagination.

if the no of employees is very hing in DB, and If I want to load in to ehCache / hibernate 2nd level cache during application start up - then how Can I able to do that ?

ehCache provides cache warm up interface to load the data into cache before cache is available to the Application?

How Can i achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

Spring Roo generates (*almost*) simple Spring + Hibernate application. So, you just must follow the [hibernate documentation to configure 2nd level cache](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/performance.html#performance-cache). Roo will not disturb on any Hibernate annotation in your classes or changes in the `persistence.xml` file.

[Here](http://howtodoinjava.com/2013/07/04/hibernate-ehcache-configuration-tutorial/) you will find a tutorial about it. Sure there are tons of information about it.

Good luck!